# How to pass a value from a function to another in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

My problem is that I have two string Values in a function called `showAuth()`, and I need to call them in another function called `setup()`. **Both functions are in the same activity file**. How can I do that?

**createActivity**

```
class createActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create)

    setup() //<---- this one says "No value passed for parameter 'email'"
}
```

**setup()**

```
   private fun setup(email: String, provider: ProviderType){

    iniciarSesionButton.setOnClickListener{
        if (inputEmail.text.isNotEmpty() && inputContraseña.text.isNotEmpty()){

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail.text.text.oString(), inputContraseña.text.toString()) .addOnCompleteListener {
                val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                db.collection("users").document(email).set(
                    hashMapOf("provider" to provider, "username" to inputUsername.text.toString())
               )
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    showAuth(it.result?.user?.email ?: "", ProviderType.Email)
                }
                else{
                    showError()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**showAuth()**

```
   private fun showAuth(email: String, provider: ProviderType){   //<-- 
    val authIntent = Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("email",email)
        putExtra("provider",provider.name)
        setup(email,provider)
    }
    startActivity(authIntent)
}
```

Comment: Define `setup` as having two parameters, i.e. `fun setup(valueA: String, valueB: String)`, and inside `showAuth`, you would pass the values when calling `setup`, e.g. `setup(firstValue, secondValue)`.

Comment: Alternatively, make two String properties in the class. `showAuth` can set the values of those [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html), and `setup` can refer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     fun showAuth( ){
        
        setup("v1", "v2")
    }


    fun setup(  valueOne :  String,valueTwo : String){
    }
```

Comment: Use Kotlin naming conventions.

Comment: is it okay now ?

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for your quick reply! I was testing it, but when I call setup() on my createActivity, it says setup() is not getting those two strings.

Comment: "it says setup() is not getting those two strings" This phrase makes no sense, what do you mean? Can you show what your code looks like?

Comment: I edited the post, it's up there. Also, on the createActivity, I made a comment.

Comment: private fun setup(email: String, provider: ProviderType) The problem is here..
 use this 
private fun setup()

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `setup` without telling it what `email` and `provider` are. What would it use for those?

Comment: First it was to create an account with email and password, but now I'm using it to save username and provider on a database when clicking that button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your **setup()** function. Please remove these two parameters "email: String, provider: ProviderType" from setup() method.It should be like this.

```
private fun setup(){

iniciarSesionButton.setOnClickListener{
    if (inputEmail.text.isNotEmpty() && inputContraseña.text.isNotEmpty()){

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail.text.text.oString(), inputContraseña.text.toString()) .addOnCompleteListener {
            val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            db.collection("users").document(email).set(
                hashMapOf("provider" to provider, "username" to inputUsername.text.toString())
           )
            if(it.isSuccessful){
                showAuth(it.result?.user?.email ?: "", ProviderType.Email)
            }
            else{
                showError()
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Doing that won't pass the two strings to setup().

Comment: yes, you are taking these two strings  from  edittext  field ("inputEmail.text.isNotEmpty() && inputContraseña.text.isNotEmpty()" )   inside the setup()method according to your code. Then why do you need to pass these ?

Comment: Please accept this answer if solved your issue.